# If I accidentally agree for new WhatsApp's terms and conditions, How to revert that?

Tags: whatsapp

WhatsApp team updates their policy and it will be from Feb 8. I accidentally agreed with the policy. Later I realized the policy is not good.

**How can I revert my agreement with the WhatsApp team?**

We have alternatives like Signal and telegram but I like to use WhatsApp. I am thinking if most of us not agree with WhatsApp's policy then they will change their decision.

---

This question is asked on Law [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60031/if-i-accidentally-agree-for-new-whatsapps-terms-and-conditions-how-to-revert-t)

Comment: This is more a legal question than a security question, i.e. off-topic here and maybe on-topic on [law.se]. But there is unlikely an easy "undo".

Comment: Reinstall app. It may ask you to agree again.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60031/if-i-accidentally-agree-for-new-whatsapps-terms-and-conditions-how-to-revert-t

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb with these things, the only way to disagree with the terms of use is by not using it.

If you're expecting that you can "revert" your agreement and only be subject to the previous terms, then I'm afraid you will be disappointed.  While a company may decide to allow that, it's highly unlikely that Facebook does in this case.  In all cases that I am aware of, abiding by terms and conditions is a requirement for using their services.

So how do you revert your agreement?  Simple.

### Stop using WhatsApp